# Lightning out App error in callback function From VF page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-out

When trying to access my VF page I am facing the following error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin
> provided ('https://mydomain-dev-ed-dev-ed.lightning.force.com') does
> not match the recipient window's origin
> ('https://mydomain-dev-ed-dev-ed--c.eu18.visual.force.com')

I am accessing my VF page from a classic button added to my page layout and rendered using `apex:detail` in the VF. The VF has the SObjectype as StandardController and overrides the View Standard page.

Simplified relevant Code:

```
<apex:page id="thePage" standardController="Custom_Object__c">
    <apex:detail inlineEdit="false" showChatter="false" title="true" />
</apex:page>

<apex:page id="thePage" standardController="Custom_Object__c">
    <apex:includeLightning/>
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:CustomApp", function() {
          $Lightning.createComponent("lightning:button",
              { label : "Press Me!" },
              "lightningvf",
              function(cmp) {
                console.log("button was created");
                // do some stuff
              }
          );
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>

<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
    <aura:dependency resource="lightning:button"/>
</aura:application>
```

**What am I doing wrong?**